# jQuery Chosen - Is there a way to let the scroll box open after selected an item?

Tags: jquery-chosen

I would like to know if we can let the scroll box open after having selected an item. In other words, the same behavior of if we hold the CTRL key and a selected item.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible without chosen script modification.

In jquery.chosen.js look for something like this (line ~955):

```
if (!((evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey) && this.is_multiple)) {
   this.results_hide();
}
```

Modify it for your needs, maybe something like:

Add new option named stay_opened (line ~155):

```
this.stay_opened = this.options.stay_opened != null ? this.options.stay_opened : true;
```

And modify mentioned code:

```
if (!((evt.metaKey || evt.ctrlKey || this.stay_opened) && this.is_multiple)) {
    this.results_hide();
}
```

Note that it will work for multiple mode only (but you can change that too).